# Can I please get some test code help with these classes?

Tags: unit-test

an somebody please help me write the test code for these two classes ? They both seem simple enough, but I'm a total rookie when it comes to test code.

I really appreciate any help I can get.

EDIT : This is how the code stands right now. I've included the test code I got from @sfdcfox at the end of the TaskEventWrapper class, but am getting an 'Invalid ID : Test' error with it.

```
 public with sharing class TaskEventWrapper {

    public String Subject {set;get;}
    public Id RelatedTo {set;get;}
    public Id RelatedToName {set;get;}  
    public DateTime DueDate {set;get;}
    public String Status {set;get;}
    public String Priority {set;get;}
    public String AssignedTo {set;get;}
    public String TaskEventRecordType {set;get;}
    public String whoId {set;get;}
    public String whoName {set;get;}
    public DateTime LastModifiedDateTime {set;get;}
    public Boolean isTask {set;get;}

    public TaskEventWrapper(String Subject, Id RelatedTo, String RelatedToName,DateTime DueDate, String Status, String Priority, String AssignedTo, String TaskEventRecordType, String whoId, String whoName, DateTime LastModifiedDateTime, Boolean isTask) {

        this.Subject = Subject;
        this.RelatedTo = RelatedTo;
        this.RelatedToName = RelatedToName;
        this.DueDate = DueDate;
        this.Status= Status;
        this.Priority = Priority;
        this.AssignedTo = AssignedTo;
        this.TaskEventRecordType = TaskEventRecordType;
        this.whoId = whoId;
        this.whoName = whoName;
        this.LastModifiedDateTime = LastModifiedDateTime;
        this.isTask = isTask;
    }
    @isTest static void test() {
    Account a = new Account(Name='Test');
    insert a;
    Contact c = new Contact(LastName='Test', AccountId=a.Id);
    insert c;
    Id rcId = Task.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().values()[0].getRecordTypeId();
    TaskEventWrapper w = new TaskEventWrapper('Subject', a.Id, a.Name, Date.Today(), 'Open', 'Low', UserInfo.getUserId(), rcId, c.Id, c.Name, DateTime.Now(), true);
    }
}
```

and this one which has 40% code coverage :

```
public class CurrencyConversion{

    Public Map<String,Decimal> currencyMap;

    public void populateMap(){
        CurrencyType[] tmpTypes = [SELECT ConversionRate, IsoCode FROM CurrencyType where IsActive=true];

        if(tmpTypes!=null&&tmpTypes.size()>0){
            currencyMap = new Map<String,Decimal>();

            //Add to map
            for(CurrencyType cType:tmpTypes){
                if(!currencyMap.containsKey(cType.IsoCode)){
                    currencyMap.put(cType.IsoCode,cType.ConversionRate);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Decimal convertCurrency(String fromISOCode, String toISOCode, decimal Value){
        if(fromISOCode==null){System.debug('From ISO Code is Null');}
        if(toISOCode==null){System.debug('To ISO Code is Null');}
        if(Value==null){System.debug('Value is Null');}

        if(currencyMap==null||currencyMap.size()>0){System.debug('CurrencyMap is Null');}

        if(currencyMap!=null&&currencyMap.size()>0){
            System.debug('Contains From Key:' + String.valueOf(currencyMap.containsKey(fromISOCode)));
            System.debug('Contains To Key:' + String.valueOf(currencyMap.containsKey(fromISOCode)));
            //Calculate
            Decimal fromRate=currencyMap.get(fromISOCode);
            Decimal toRate=currencyMap.get(toISOCode);



            //comvert to USD first.
            Value = Value/fromRate;

            System.debug('Converted USD Value:' + String.valueOf(Value));

            //convert to new currency
            Value=Value*toRate;
            System.debug('Converted Value:' + Value.setScale(2));
            return Value.setScale(2);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for any help you can give me. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you can post your existing test class code.

Comment: In addition to posting existing test code, can you explain where you're stuck? What have you tried to improve your tests so far? Have you read any of the guides published by Salesforce?

Comment: There is no existing test code. I shouldn't have said one of them had %40 coverage.

Answer (score 5):

For a data-only class, simply call its constructor in a test method:

```
@isTest static void test() {
    Account a = new Account(Name='Test');
    insert a;
    Contact c = new Contact(LastName='Test', AccountId=a.Id);
    insert c;
    Id rcId = Task.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().values()[0].getRecordTypeId();
    TaskWrapper w = new TaskEventWrapper('Subject', a.Id, a.Name, Date.Today(), 'Open', 'Low', UserInfo.getUserId(), rcId, c.Id, c.Name, DateTime.Now(), true);
}
```

For a logic class, you have to (1) populate sample data, (2) instantiate the class, and (3) test its logic and output.

```
@isTest static void test() {
    CurrencyType[] cTypes = new CurrencyType[0];
    // Create some currency values.
    insert cTypes;
    CurrencyConversion controller = new CurrencyConversion();
    Test.startTest();
    controller.populateMap();
    Decimal testResult = controller.convertCurrency('USD','EUR',5);
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertEquals(5.75, testResult); // Or whatever value is expected.
}
```

*Update* Added a fuller example for wrapper class.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I'm trying to use the TaskEventWrapper test. I thought I would only need to start putting in values for fields (ie Subject = 'Test' etc) But I'm being told I can only do that for an SObject. How should I finish out that test ? Thanks again.

Comment: Added an expanded example for this. Basically, you have to provide some value for all the parameters.

Comment: sfdcfox : I'm getting an error telling me 'Invalid id : Test'. Do you know what that is ? Thanks

Comment: If you already have a class or object named 'Test', please remove it or rename it.

Comment: @TechMatrix - There is no other class or object named 'Test'. Do you have any other idea why I may be getting the 'Invalid ID : Test' error ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The goal of writing test cases apart from meeting the test coverage limit of 75% is to ensure that:

1. You are testing all code paths.
2. Your code is working as expected.

The IDE and the UI will tell you which lines are not included in the test coverage so you can modify your test cases,

Your first class is just a wrapper class with a constructor where you are initializing the fields of the class.

So the test case will be simple for this one. Just declare and initialize an object of this class.

For the second class, try this as a starting point.

```
   @isTest
   public static void testMethod1() 
   {
        test.StartTest();
        CurrencyConversion con = new CurrencyConversion ();
        //Assuming you have currency records. Else create new ones here first.
        con.populateMap();

        //Test cases for code path coverage
        con.convertCurrency('USD', 'CAD', 100);
        con.convertCurrency('USD', 'EUD', 100);
        con.convertCurrency('USD', 'AUD', 100);
        con.convertCurrency('USD', 'CAD', 100);
        con.convertCurrency('USD', null, 100);
        con.convertCurrency(null, 'USD', 100);
        con.convertCurrency('USD', 'AUD', 0);


        //Test cases to check code is working
        Decimal expectedValue = <enter value here>;
        Decimal ActualValue= con.convertCurrency('USD','EUR',50);
        System.assertEquals(expectedValue , ActualValue);

        //Add more test cases as needed.

        test.StopTest();

   }
```

Comment: Your second point is very important: functional test cases are a Good Thing.

Comment: @Richard N - Thank you very much for this ! Do you have an idea for the TaskEventWrapper class ? I've gotten other help on here but I am getting errors.

Comment: Please add your new test class to your question above so we can see your code and help you faster.